# How to get the last file content generated in "Get file content using path" Power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, word, help

I'm making an application to populate a Word document, I found a method to do this by taking an item from a Sharepoint library. I would like it to take, instead of a specific image, the last image sent there.

[image: image of my flux]

After "/Teste Laudos/_______" there is a JPG image, I would like it to be the last one sent to the library, and not this specific one.